# How to select distinct values two columns where one column is does not have duplicate values

Tags: sql, oracle, rdbms

I have a student balance table in which the student id not duplicate but the balance is duplicate. I want to select only one of each balance as a sample with their student id. this is the screen shot of my table.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhdMO.jpg)

My database is in oracle 19c.
I want to display distinct balances as a sample of each for ex. 1,10,20,50 along with their student id which can be any id. as shown below.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRGdU.jpg)

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [mre] [ask] [Help] [research effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [“help me"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3404097) [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097)

Answer (score 1):

As student ID can be *any*, then use e.g. `min` aggregate function.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with student (stid, balance) as
  2    (select 101, 10 from dual union all
  3     select 102, 20 from dual union all
  4     select 103,  5 from dual union all
  5     select 104, 50 from dual union all
  6     select 105,  5 from dual union all
  7     select 106,  5 from dual union all
  8     select 107, 10 from dual union all
  9     select 108, 10 from dual union all
 10     select 120,  1 from dual union all
 11     select 121, 50 from dual union all
 12     select 121, 10 from dual
 13    )
```

Query:

```
 14  select min(stid) stid, balance
 15  from student
 16  group by balance
 17  order by balance;

      STID    BALANCE
---------- ----------
       120          1
       103          5
       101         10
       102         20
       104         50

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you for your support, but you have manually selected and combined each select statement by union all. But I have a huge amount of data from which my management may ask me to retrieve data where balances are some other values e.g. (35,47,60,70). I tried the dense_ranking to assign a rank and then apply distinct on the rank but it does not remove the duplicate values from the ranking column. My query                                                    select distinct(dense_rank() over (order by balance desc)) ranking, stdid,balance
from stdbalances where balance in(1,5,10,20,50)

Comment: I don't have your table and didn't feel like creating one; that's why I used CTE (Common table expression, also known as WITH factoring clause). If you provided CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO sample data, I wouldn't have to do that. As I said: that's **sample data**. You already have it in your table and certainly wouldn't do it. Query you need begins at line #14, which is also marked with appropriate word: "Query:". If that's not it, then - please - edit your question, post CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO sample data which illustrates the problem, as well as desired result (based on that sample).

Comment: I'm sorry I am new to this site. "Thank You So Much"

Answer (score -1):

you have to decide how do you want to pick the balance. Should it be a minimum? Maximum? something else?
If all you want is a sample it shouldn't make a big difference.
Then do a group by on student ID and that should give you the result set you're looking for.